# Web2Py - Setting up appliances/applications

Tags: web-applications, web2py, web2py-modules

I'm using web2py to create my webpage. I checked some applications for web2py in

https://github.com/mdipierro/web2py-appliances

I tried to set up an app but I have no idea how I can do it.

The apps didn't have web2py.py file to run as a "Project" so I imagine that I have to "Import" the files but...

**How can I integrate this app's to my web2py website?**

Thanks at all

***EDIT1:
I've done !
I didn't saw there was a .w2p file in the files project. I just can imported to the file manager.
I just can't answer my question because of my low rep***

Answer (score 0):

The answer from the OP:

I've done ! I didn't saw there was a .w2p file in the files project. I just can imported to the file manager. I just can't answer my question because of my low rep.